# How to disable pinterest option in UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I want to disable Pinterest option from appearing in UIActivityViewController. How can it be done?

Comment: I agree that it would be very useful if Pinterest and other apps did not show for files which they cannot handle!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `excludedActivityTypes` property on `UIActivityViewController`?

From the docs:

> This property contains an array of strings, each of which corresponds
>   to the value you would find in the activityType parameter of a
>   UIActivity object. Each string you specify indicates a service that
>   you do not want displayed to the user. You might exclude services that
>   you feel are not suitable for the content you are providing. For
>   example, you might not want to allow the user to print a specific
>   image. If the value of this property is nil, no services are excluded.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller